# XCode - C++ with obj-C examples?

Tags: iphone

I am looking to develop an applicate for OS X with Apple's XCode for the iPhone. I have a few classes that I have defined for Visual C++, but they should be fairly cross-platform. So I would like to use those C++ classes, but my impression is that the GUI builder and everything else is built to use obj-C. Are there any examples of mixing these two languages into the same app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C and C++ work together mostly seamlessly. You can store Objective-C objects in C++ classes, structs and collections, and vice-versa. The one caveat is that Objective-C classes won't call constructors or destructors on C++ data members unless the `Call C++ Default Ctor/Dtors in Objective-C` compiler option is set. But, since this is set by default on the current version of Xcode, this shouldn't be an issue.

On the whole, mixing C++ and Objective-C works very well, and is almost a universal practice in game development, since C++ provides much better support for math libraries.

Comment: @Sweety If you think this is a good answer, you should up-vote it, and mark it with a check-mark as accepted.

Comment: Actually, Objective-C objects can and will call constructors and destructors. You just need to be sure to set the appropriate compiler flag (which IIRC is on by default on all recent Xcode versions.)

Comment: ya i know that i should up-vote, but for the up-vote reputation must be 16 and above and my reputation is 10.....

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks for the correction. That's the handiest thing I've learned all day!

Comment: ...I've amended my answer accordingly.